# Active Directory - Reset User Password using User Principal Name in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Not even sure if this is possible? Is there a way to reset the AD password for a user using just the User Principal Name. Normally, I have to rely on their AD username.

Their UPN is the same as their email address and that's what I'd like to use.

So for example, for a user called John Smith, his UPN/Email is joh.smith@thiscompany.com and his AD account name (SAM name) would be Jsmith. For now, I've mainly been doing the below:

Confirm Security question:

```
Get-ADUser jsmith -Properties * | Select RD8SecurityQuestions
```

Change Password:

```
Set-ADAccountPassword jsmith -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "password1" -Force -Verbose) -PassThru
```

Require password change on next logon:

```
Set-ADUser -Identity jsmith -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

So far, I've figured out you can get the security question by doing:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {EmailAddress -eq 'john.smith@thiscompany.com'} -Properties * | Select RD8SecurityQuestions
```

But I'm not how to do the other two steps or if there's something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question, unfortunately, the `-Identity` parameter only accepts of the following:

> - A distinguished name
> - A GUID (objectGUID)
> - A security identifier (objectSid)
> - A SAM account name (sAMAccountName)

Though, this parameter accepts pipeline input, so, `Get-ADUser ... | Set-ADAccountPassword` should work without problems.

---

**Note:** Thanks [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658691/active-directory-reset-user-password-using-user-principal-name-in-powershell#comment121338813_68658838) for pointing out 2 points I missed:

1. It is not recommended to no use a ScriptBlock on the `-Filter` parameter as it can be prone to errors. Last option of `$adUsr = Get-AdUser...` from my code (`-Filter {...}).`
2. When querying Active Directory, it is always a good practice (and also for efficiency) to call only the properties you need query (`-Properties RD8SecurityQuestions`) instead of querying all properties (`-Properties *`). For one user it is fine but if you need to query thousands of users you **will** note the difference and your Domain Controllers will be thankful too :)

---

Try any of the following:

```
$params = @{
    Reset = $true
    NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "password1" -Force
    PassThru = $true
}

$upn = 'joh.smith@thiscompany.com'

# Chose one of these options:
$adUsr = Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(UserPrincipalName=$upn)" -Properties RD8SecurityQuestions
$adUsr = Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$upn'" -Properties RD8SecurityQuestions
$adUsr = Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq '$upn'} -Properties RD8SecurityQuestions

# Confirm Security Questions
$aduser | Select-Object RD8SecurityQuestions

# Then:
$adUsr | Set-ADAccountPassword @params

# Lastly:
$adUsr | Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true
```

Comment: Generally we try to discourage users from using a scriptblock in the `-Filter` parameter. While it does work a lot of the time, it's not really supported and may cause issues. Also, don't forget to add `-Properties RD8SecurityQuestions` as the user wants to be able to ask the security question before resetting the password. Much better than `-Prop *`

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @TheMadTechnician

Comment: Hey Santiago, thanks for noticing that I'd left the domain in, I really appreciate it. Also props for the code. Tried to reset the password and require change on first log-on with the below command but for some reason it only changed the password, it didn't require a change on the first logon:

Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(UserPrincipalName=john.smith@thiscompany.com)" -Properties RD8SecurityQuestions | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Password2021" -Force -Verbose) -PassThru | Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true

Comment: @Jaden43 hey, no problem. I wasn't sure if you can `Set-ADAccountPassword.... -PassThru | Set-ADUser ....` that's why I divided the code in 3 steps.